# Connection to APM Server timed out (url: http://localhost:8200/intake/v2/events

Tags: elasticsearch, flask, apm

I have a configuration as follows:

1. Single elastic node (separate from the rest)
2. Kibana setup on a separate node
3. APM server on it's own node
4. Flask Application set up on an it's own node.

Versions:
Kibana and Elastic (opendistro): v 7.10.2
APM OSS: apm-server-oss-7.12.1-amd64.deb

Essentially I have instrumented my python flask app to push data to APM server but when I try to ingest data from APM in Kibana, I get

1. APM Server response: You have correctly setup APM Server
2. Agent status: No data has been received from agents yet

My Python flask app has the following structure

```
import sqlite3, requests, time, logging
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from elasticapm.contrib.flask import ElasticAPM
from elasticapm.handlers.logging import LoggingHandler

app = Flask(__name__)
apm = ElasticAPM(app, server_url='http://apm-oss.site:8200', service_name='APM-TEST-APP', logging=False)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify({"message": "response ok"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

My APM server has the following config

```
apm-server:
  host: "0.0.0.0:8200"

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["https://esnode.site:9200"]
  ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/apm-server/pki/root-ca.pem"]
  ssl.certificate: "/etc/apm-server/pki/client.pem"
  ssl.key: "/etc/apm-server/pki/client-key.pem"
  enabled: true

kibana:
  enabled: true
  host: "192.168.56.112:5601"
  username: "admin"
  password: "admin"
```

When I perform a curl against the python flask endpoint against port 80 I get the response below

```
Jun  1 15:30:58 app python3.6[24523]: 192.168.56.115 - - [01/Jun/2021 15:30:58] "#033[37mGET / HTTP/1.1#033[0m" 200 -
Jun  1 15:30:59 app python3.6[24523]: 192.168.56.115 - - [01/Jun/2021 15:30:59] "#033[37mGET / HTTP/1.1#033[0m" 200 -
```

Looking at the APM syslog, the following entries coincide with the previous curl commands which seem to be processing the incoming logs from the app server

```
Jun  1 15:49:03 apm-oss apm-server[7064]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2021-06-01T15:49:03.272Z","log.logger":"request","log.origin":{"file.name":"middleware/log_middleware.go","file.line":63},"message":"request accepted","url.original":"/intake/v2/events","http.request.method":"POST","user_agent.original":"elasticapm-python/6.1.3","source.address":"192.168.56.114","http.request.body.bytes":450,"http.request.id":"dcdc7497-de2a-41fc-8fd9-03c06949fd8f","event.duration":305562,"http.response.status_code":202,"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
```

It does appear that the APM instance is receiving data but Kibana is saying no agents are up.

Anyone seen this and resolved it. Suggestions greatly appreciated.